# Browser shows IP and port in the url bar for sub-domain

Tags: ip, subdomain, domain-name, url

We have a sub domain name like support.mycompany.com. When we write this in browser, it works as expected but the sub-domain changes to IP and port in the url bar. Why is this happening ? What should we do to keep seeing the sub domain name ?

I am using an apache server on ubuntu os that listens on port 88  (its a vm running on xen server). Other than this no advanced config is done

Comment: When you browse to subdomain.domain.com you are redirected to the IP address? What is at that address? Are there any redirects taking place on that page? What web server?

Comment: Change the web server configuration so that it no longer issues a redirect.

Comment: Thank you for posting on ServerFault. Getting good answers requires the effort of [writing a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and as it stands now yours is missing sufficient detail (what webserver, how are you redirecting, your actual configuration etc.) to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: Its an apache server.  Let me check the config

Comment: I'd suggest searching your apache2.conf for 'Redirect' or 'Rewrite'.

Comment: @DylanKnoll I have found out that the sub domain is redirected to the firewall initially

Comment: That'll do it... I assume it's an application firewall like F5 ASM or similar? You should be able to configure it to use the desired address.

Comment: It may happen if you do have wrong DNS configuration